How to execute the method passed as an Expression<Action<T>> argument when the function withing the expression is asynchronous?
I have a .net-core web service which I use to execute argument actions with the type Expression<Action<T>> when runing Integration tests:
// this is the usual pattern to call the service
_backgroundTasksService.RunBackgroundTask<MyService>(x => x.Execute(id, name, color));



// and this is the service which stubs the calls for unit tests:
public class BackgroundTasksServiceStub : IBackgroundTasksService {
  private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

  public BackgroundTasksServiceStub(IServiceProvider serviceProvider){
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
  }

  public void RunBackgroundTask<T>(Expression<Action<T>> methodCall){
    var service = _serviceProvider.GetService<T>();
    var method = methodCall.Compile();
    method(service);
  }
}

Calling this stub service works fine when 'MyService.Execute' is a synchronous method, but it misbehaves when 'MyService.Execute' is async (async Task...)  ...
What should I do so this stub service can handle the call to async methods synchronously?
Btw, I know that the actual service works fine, so there is a way! Only misbehaves on the unit tests This is the first question I got answered on this matter.

Just out of curiosity - why do you pass Expression not just Action?

That is the argument type used by the third party lib the actual service uses

"Btw, I know that the actual service works fine, so there is a way" - it depends on what do you consider to be fine. Current implementation results in fire-and-forget task launched which can have a lot of implications.

As for the problem -  with Action<T> it would not be easy. You will need to analyze the body and check if the call actually returns a Task. Ideally you should consider using Func<T, object>and check ifobjectis aTask`.

This question is similar to: Check if Action is async lambda. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is not an Async lambda.... the expression contains a calll to 'MyService.Execute', and this second one is async
